# Sorting array of custom objects by its variable

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, sorting

I've created a custom class to hold image and its string(its name)

```
class Countries: NSObject {

var countryName : String
var countryFlag : UIImage

init(countryName: String, countryFlag: UIImage) {
    self.countryName = countryName
    self.countryFlag = countryFlag
    super.init()

}
```

}

I declared the class

```
    var myList: Array<Countries> = []
```

And add each country info to the array

```
let image = UIImage(data:imageData!)

let dd = Countries(countryName: object["CountryName"] as! String, countryFlag: image!)

self.myList.append(dd)
```

I tried below code to sort the array but doesn't work;

```
self.myList.sortInPlace({ $0.countryName < $1.countryName })
```

Does anybody has idea how can I sort my array according to above code?

Comment: Why doesn't the thing work that you wrote?

Comment: Basically the code is correct. What error message(s) do you get?

Comment: I didn't get any error, It just doesn't sort the array by countryName.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort an array like this using `-sortUsingComparator:`, which you pass a block into. The block takes the two objects you want to compare and returns a `NSComparisonResult` which is your comparison of the two. You could provide a block that uses `countryName`.

You could alternatively use `-sortUsingDescriptors:` and pass in a `NSSortDescriptor` that looks at the `countryName` field.

Comment: I'll try two above method you mentioned and let you know. Thanks.